# what endpoint should i include when searching for multiple categories and sub category using the foursquare API

Tags: android, foursquare

Hi i am delevloping an app and need to know how to access the endpoit url when i want to perform a search for a category or multiple catagories when using the foursquare API. That is how to i build my Url to return a specific category. and how do i combine it with the API endpoit of venues search

Comment: So do you need guidence to call api or you need FS api ?

Comment: yes.. i am actually calling data from foursquare API and google Places APi and i need the result to be returned as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a comma separated list of category ids in the "categoryId" param for /venues/search which will filter returned venues to those in those categories.

Comment: could like give me an example dont really understand what you mean thanks